# How do I install guix on 21.04

Tags: apt

How do I install guix on 21.04? After "apt-get install guix" I cannot run guix pull

guix pull: error: failed to connect to `/var/guix/daemon-socket/socket': No such file or directory

It seems that directory is not created. The binary installation page on the guix site describes some steps that don't seem to have been performed with the apt install while others have.

I can't find any documentation in the installation that describes additional installation instructions.

edit: the output of service status guix-daemon

```
  guix-daemon.service: Failed to locate executable /var/guix/profiles/per-user/root/current-guix/bin/guix-daemon: No such file or directory
```

edit: Solved: There was an old  guix-daemon systemd file in /etc/ from a previous manual binary installation. Deleted it and systemctl daemon-reload; systemctl restart guix-daemon fixed it.

Comment: Sounds like it's not running. Can you update your question to include the output of the following commands: `ps aux | grep -I guix` and `sudo service guix-daemon service`

Comment: /var/guix doesn't exist and that's why it isn't running (that should be the  location of the daemon binary)

Comment: Solved. See edit in original post

Comment: Please move solution to the answer below.

Answer (score 0):

If you encounter a similar issue, this should be the solution below (as solved by OP themself):

It is probably caused by an old `guix-daemon systemd` file in `/etc/` from a previous manual binary installation.

> - Delete this file (the old `guix-daemon systemd` file).
> - Run the following commands on your terminal to reload `daemon` and restart `guix-daemon`:
>
>   ```
>   $ systemctl daemon-reload 
>   $ systemctl restart guix-daemon
>   ```

Everything should be OK now.

Comment: @N0rbert I believe this should be OK now, but I couldn't edit the OP's question to remove the section under "edit: Solved:" since I have too many pending edits. Quopola, please you could remove the said section and accept this answer if it's OK? Thank you.